# Как проверить открыты ли вкладка tabpage1, winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

У меня есть несколько вкладок tabControl, и надобность проверить какая вкладка открыта, что бы изменять значение свойства формы AutoScroll = true (если taBage1) в иных случаях AutoScroll = false.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [SelectedTab](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedtab?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) или [SelectedIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindex?view=windowsdesktop-7.0).